# Convert NSString to hexvalue and to apply to UILabel

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I have a color code in 6 digit hex format like 3333fb, now I have to convert it to 0X3333fb hexadecimal value and have to set it as UILabel text color or tableview cell textlabel color.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: A link-only answer below has been provided, which may be deleted in due course. It [points here](http://imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-convert-hex-color-string-to-uicolor.php) currently.

Answer (score 1):

Try this macro:

```
// Get a UIColor from a hex value --> UIColor* c = HEXCOLOR(0xff00ffff);
#define HEXCOLOR(c) [UIColor colorWithRed:((c>>24)&0xFF)/255.0 \
                                    green:((c>>16)&0xFF)/255.0 \
                                     blue:((c>>8)&0xFF)/255.0 \
                                    alpha:((c)&0xFF)/255.0]
```

When you want to have a UIColor simply do this:

```
HEXCOLOR(0x3333fbFF)
```